# Is it possible in chrome devtools to lock some layer of DOM that won't be selectable when inspecting DOM without removing or hiding it?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, chrome-devtools-protocol

In many drawing software/app, you can lock a layer so it's not annoying when you try to use your mouse to pick some element/shape inside it.

However, I'm encountering the same problem with my chrome devtools. Especially when dealing with SVG shapes.

For instance, I want to lock this huge layer `.green_background` so it won't affecting me inspecting my small rects inside the graph.

Is it possible for ChromeDevTools?
[image]